# Loading Pgp files to local DB

Tags: sql, pgp

is there any way how to load *.pgp from ftp://ftp.prato.linux.it/pub/keyring/ to the local database (for instance MySQL) ?

Those *.pgp look like binaries so I have been trying to load them to Berkeley DB (following http://www.keysigning.org/sks/ with /usr/local/bin/sks_build.sh
from sks-keyserver) and then make a readable dump but everytime it fails with errors.

Comment: Yes, PGP files are indeed binary ones and you need to store them in BLOB fields. And what your actual question is?

Comment: The question is whether exists any direct way how to load records (keys,id,etc) to (for example) local MySQL db. I found a way using gpg client to convert the pgp records to plaintext and subsequently load them to db. But I was hoping that exists direct way how to achieve that.

Comment: The direct way is to load binary data to BLOBs. Any other way involves data conversion.

Comment: Thank You. Do you know way how to convert the data? I tried (cli) gpg client to list them and redirect output to the plaintext file but after few records an error occurred
"gpg: mpi too large for this implementation (56104 bits)
gpg: mpi too large for this implementation (31822 bits)
gpg: mpi too large for this implementation (35677 bits)"

Comment: PGP files can be BASE64-encoded or armored both by your code or using gnupg, but command-line utilities are not exactly on topic here on SO.

Comment: I was searching for something like that [hockey puck loader](https://github.com/hockeypuck/hockeypuck/blob/master/cmd/hockeypuck/load.go).

Comment: "Give me the code" questions are not welcome on SO. They are offtopic.